# Do const if statements do the same thing as #ifdef macros in Go?

Tags: go

There's no text preprocessing in Go. Like Java and others like it, if I want to remove a block of code I can use a `const` value and surround the code with an `if`.

If I do this, does the compiler optimise the code from the AST and out of the generated code? Or is the condition executed each time?

EDIT: If I want to replicate `#ifdef` what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Any decent compiler will optimize this out. Doing optimizations while constructing the AST (like GCC does) would be moronic, though.

Comment: Yes but does the Go compiler do it? Also, what's wrong with optimising ASTs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If statements with constant conditions are not the same as `#ifdef` because the code inside is always compiled no matter what. However, the compilers do optimize it away when possible. Consider this program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    if false {
        fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

If we run `go tool 6g -S test.go`, here's the assembly output for the `main` function:

```
--- prog list "main" ---
0000 (test.go:7) TEXT    main+0(SB),$40-0
0001 (test.go:11) RET     ,
```

The dead code is gone so all it does is return.

If you do need to actually conditionally compile parts of your code, it's best to do it through the build system.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! But what build system? I saw in one of the videos something along the lines of "in order to make `go build` simple we removed most parts you'd recognise as traditionally part of the build system, such as text preprocessing". From your answer, the `if` is the right way to go, but text processing would be the only way to simulate `#ifdef`, right?

Comment: You can pass in tags to `go build` through the -tags flag. Then you can conditionally build files by placing things like `// +build tag` or `// +build !tag` in the file. See this documentation: http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/